# QAbstractItemModel::index

Tags: c++, qt

Изучаю модель/представления QT, и столкнутся вот с какой проблемой, а точнее с одной страной функцией под названием:

```
bool QAbstractItemModel::hasIndex(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const
```

которая используется в примере Qt по построению простой модели дерева в функции:

```
QModelIndex TreeModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent)
         const
{
  if (!hasIndex(row, column, parent))
     return QModelIndex();

 TreeItem *parentItem;

 if (!parent.isValid())
     parentItem = rootItem;
 else
     parentItem = static_cast<TreeItem*>(parent.internalPointer());

 TreeItem *childItem = parentItem->child(row);
 if (childItem)
     return createIndex(row, column, childItem);
 else
     return QModelIndex();
}
```

Почитал в доках Qt, для чего предназначена функция **hasIndex** - если коротко, то  для проверки существования индекса. Но если строка и столбец не будут равны строке и столбцу модельного индекса, то все равно **hasIndex** возвратит true.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как нужно правильно использовать **hasIndex**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот Вам реализация этой функции:

```
bool QAbstractItemModel::hasIndex(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if(row < 0 || column < 0)
        return false;
    return row < rowCount(parent) && column < columnCount(parent);
}
```

Полагаю, пояснения излишни?